# Should I implement packet delimiter with AES encrypted TCP stream?

Tags: aes, twisted

Recently I am trying to design a custom protocol for IoT devices with Python Twisted. Since most of the IoT devices (end node) are not powerful enough to support TLS, I have to implement a modified light weight transport security. However AES128/256 is used for data encryption as same as standrad TLS.

It is well known that TCP is a stream, and delivered messages may need delimiter in the TCP stream. In text oriented message like HTTP/FTP, \n\r is used. In binary message, we should define our own structure such as TLV and V stands for payload data. That can be implemented by Netty in Java, Twisted in Python.

When TCP is encrypted, things become complicated. In theory, plain text should be encrypted with AES, then carried on TCP stream. It is easy for text message, but in binary message, Type/Length fields are encrypted as well. Furthermore, AES is block oriented algorithm, which means a message may need next message to combile to be encrypted/decrypted. Although the AES could be transparent transport, but it is hard to implement for binary message slicing and parsing.

There is another way, we can leave TL fields in TLV as plain, while keep V encrypted by AES. But it only works for binary data. and it need padding in AES as well.

Is there any suggestions or references, including code or project ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES is a block cipher, so read data in chunks of the block size. On the transmitter side, your AES encryption code should add padding as necessary, it should be part of the AES implementation. (I would recommend that you use AES-CBC for this application). On the transmitter, just read data in chunks of the block size.

In java I would use an DataInputStream from my socket, and do a readFully().

```
Socket socket;
DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

while(connectionOpen) {
   byte[] aes = new Byte[blockSize];
   ins.readFully(aes);
   //Decrypt received data aes
   ...
}
```

Since you use readFully() above, you ensure you always receive data of the correct size, i.e. the block size.

Comment: Read the data in multiples of the block size and only pad the last block.

Comment: Now, I got it. with AES, things becomes more simpler. The receiver just read chunks of block size (like 16B/32B). And the padding method even can help receiver to delimit the packet streams !